# How segmentation enables sharing of code or data?

Tags: virtual-memory, memory-segmentation

I read that  there are segments of each process (stack segment, code segment) and each virtual address has segment number and offset this scheme allows code sharing between processes. I didn't understand the idea of sharing please explain the **sharing** with an example ?

Answer (score 0):

What  you are describing is largely obsolete. The use of segments was a kludge in the early intel processors that needlessly lived on for decades. Segments go away with 64 bit intel.The segment is usually specified using a register, not as part of the address.

As to your question, in theory multiple processes could share the same same code segment. However, this is easier said than done because a process's code [segment] is usually loaded from multiple sources.